# Remove duplicate data in a CSV file

Tags: vbscript

I'm actually coding a script to remove duplicates in a CSV file of 12'000 rows. I know this file has duplicates on userid AND/OR on card_number, its format is like:

```
userid  fistname  lastname   card_number
-------------------------------------------
 1234   toto      help        111111
 1234   toto      help        111111
```

AND

```
 1234   toto      help        111111
 5678   user      user2       111111
```

I would like to read the lines one by one and add them in a dictionary object if they are already in it, then write in another file the remaining lines and export the dictionary in a log file.

The coded functions to create/open/write/save the files using fso objects are working.

I can't get back to the dictionary method which seems not working.

I have no clue on how to export my dictionary or maybe is it only due to the fact that the dictionary is not working.

I have made a lot of research on stackoverflow, ssh64 or expert-exchange to find solutions but I'm blocked, I suppose I'm almost there with my script but any help would be really appreciated.

````
```
`
`This is the dictionary part to record duplicates 
`in a file and remove them from the destination file
`
```
`
`# Declares required variables
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objTextFile, objFile
Dim strDirectory, CurDir, InputFile, OutputFile 
Dim strInput, strFile
Dim dictionary, it

`# Here we go !
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemobject") 
Set OutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(CurDir & ".\myCSVfile.csv", 2, true)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(CurDir & InputFile, 1)

`# Reads the file until the end
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

    strInput = objFile.ReadLine()
    strInput = Trim(strInput)
    If Len(strInput) > 0 Then
        'WScript.Echo strInput
        'OutputLog.Writeline strInput
        'Quit
    End If

    `# Test if it already exists, if YES, it's a duplicate
    If Not dictionary.exists(strInput) Then
        OutputFile.Writeline strInput
    Else
        dictionary.add strInput, null
        If dictionary.Count >= 0 Then
            objTextFile.Write dictionary.items
        Else
            objTextFile.Write "There are " & dictionary.Count & "  duplicated data in the file."
        End If
    End if

Loop

`# Populate the log file with the duplicated entries
For Each it In dictionary
    .Item  = it & "" & dictionary(it)
    objTextFile.Writeline .Item
Next
````

Expected results:

- the dictionary to be populated with duplicates
- the log file to be written with duplicates
- the duplicates to be removed from the final file

Actual results:

- open the input file
- read the input file
- create the output file
- write the output file
- open the log file
- write the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each dictionary value requires a key, so if you treat each line in the input as a key, and duplicate it for the value, this is a very simple way of making it work. There's more code in setting up cleaning up then the processing code itself. BTW, you could pass in an Array as the dictionary value if you wanted to get sophisticated. and loop over the dictionary and array value, but it looked as if you just wanted to compare lines.

```
dict.Add "Key", Split(line, ",")
```

I used your examples and 4 of 6 should be unique:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso : set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fileIn : set fileIn = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\users\user\desktop\input.txt")
Dim fileOut : set fileOut = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\users\user\desktop\output.txt", 2, true) ' for writing/create
Dim dictlog : set dictlog = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\users\user\desktop\dictlog.txt", 2, true) ' for writing/create
Dim dict : set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim key
dim line

Do Until fileIn.AtEndOfStream
    key = fileIn.ReadLine
    line = key

    if Not dict.exists(key) Then
        dict.Add key, line      
        fileOut.WriteLine line
    else
        dictLog.WriteLine line
    end if
Loop

fileIn.Close
fileOut.Close
dictlog.Close

Set fso     = Nothing
Set fileIn  = Nothing
Set fileOut = Nothing
Set line    = Nothing
Set dict    = Nothing
set dictlog = Nothing
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, this is just awesome !

New question, what if I'd like to filter on another value inside key?

If I want to add a second condition like in the example below:

123456,N,N,Firstname,Lastname,,,11111111,,,,,,,
123456,N,Y,Firstname,Lastname,,,11111111,,,,,,,

Here, I want to compare both line and if it is "Y", I add to my dictionary the line with "Y". How can I do that please?